# How to change character set after installation of Oracle 11.2 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, oracle

I have installed Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 in Windows 10 pro for testing and learning. 
The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `WE8MSWIN1252` but I need it to be `AL32UTF8`.
How can I change the characterset after installation of Oracle 11.2 in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

If you've just created the database, drop it, and create a new one with the character set you want.

Comment: +1 I recommend this approach if possible.  It sounds extreme at first but changing character sets can lead to some weird bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) tool. It is a GUI tool that does all the scanning, recommendations and conversions step by step. It used to be a manual method with CSSCAN and CSALTER but those are deprecated. You can download DMU from Oracle's website.

Answer (score 0):

> If your database has data making this change is dangerous, as already
>   pointed out in the @sandman.

Connect as `SYS` using `Sqlplus` and execute this:

```
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AL32UTF8;
ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```

After that you can use the query below to check if it worked:

```
SELECT value
FROM nls_database_parameters
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Answer (score -1):

sqlplus sys as sysdba

password

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE

STARTUP RESTRICT

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE  AL32UTF8;

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE

STARTUP

EXIT

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database. However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.